# is there a way to compare arrays by index orders and show the difference?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two arrays and want to compare their elements by index order. when they have different items it works fine and it shows the difference but when they have same elements in different orders, it returns nothing.. here is my code, please help me.

```
array1 = [a, b, c,]
array2 = [a, x, c,]

var diff = this.array1.filter(diff => !this.array2.includes(diff));
this.showDiff = diff.toString();   // prints : x
```

but when comparing in this scenario:

```
array1 = [a, b, c]
array2 = [c, b, a]
```

I need to get this result : [a, c]

and in this scenario:

```
array1 = [a, b, c]
array2 = [c, a, b]
```

I need to get this result : [a, b, c]

but I got nothing in both scenarios.  orders is important to me when comparing.

Comment: Instead of using includes, compare against the value at the same index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the indexes matter, you need to use the index when checking the other array. `!array2.includes(diff)` doesn't do that.

The `filter` callback receives the index, so you could use it when checking:

```
var diff = this.array1.filter((diff, index) => this.array2[index] !== diff);
```

Live Example:

```js
function test(array1, array2) {
    var diff = array1.filter((diff, index) => array2[index] !== diff);
    console.log(`array1 = ${JSON.stringify(array1)}`);
    console.log(`array2 = ${JSON.stringify(array2)}`);
    console.log(`diff   = ${JSON.stringify(diff)}`);
}

test(
    ["a", "b", "c"],
    ["c", "b", "a"]
);

test(
    ["a", "b", "c"],
    ["c", "a", "b"]
);
```

Note: This doesn't make any attempt to handle issues where the arrays aren't the same length. The question didn't say what to do in that case, but a real-world solution would presumably have to handle it.

Comment: It's important to say that this will only work if `array1` has the same length or is smaller than `array2`. With `array1.length > array2.length`, you'd end up with checking a non-existant index in `array2` and an error would be raised.

Comment: @VictorOliveira - No error would be raised (`array2[index]` when `index` is `>= array2.length` results in `undefined`), but it's a very good point that you need to take array lengths into account in terms of the correctness of the result.

Comment: how can I include check for array length also?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you are correct. In my mind, when using strict mode, this would raise an error instead of returning `undefined`. My bad

Comment: @MisaghKarimi - Look at the `length` property of the arrays and do whatever it is you want this code to do when `array1.length < array2.length` or `array1.length > array2.length`.